# Do not allow users to deny app permissions

Tags: android

My whole app relies on the fact that location permissions is granted, but when the permissions dialog opens up, there is a button to deny access. Is there a way to remove the deny button, and only allow them to either exit the app or allow the permissions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this is allowed as it is overriding an android system feature. Even if you could figure it out it would probably technically violate the Google Play Store terms. (So, you'd have to turn to another market to release to...)

You should just create the UI clear to the user that the location permission is necessary and then display some sort of error message if they deny that, show them a prompt to allow it again before being able to use the app.

You can read more about it [here](https://play.google.com/about/privacy-security-deception/malicious-behavior/), notice the lines:

> Apps that monitor or track a user's behavior on a device must comply with these requirements:
>   ...
>   Apps must not hide or cloak tracking behavior or **attempt to mislead users** about such functionality.

[This page](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting) explains why and how to show your user why your app needs a certain permission.

In short, without resorting to an off brand kernel of android found on the web or something, you probably can't very easily and shouldn't anyway. (For both moral reasons, legal ones, and because like you can just show a dialog box to explain to the user why they should allow the permission... not that hard. If they want to use your app then they will allow it. Simple as that.)

Answer (score 1):

No, I don't think so that you can take control over the allow and deny options in permission because

- All the permissions are divided into two categories **normal and dangerous permission** (also called **Runtime permission**),  the normal permission are automatically granted as you install the app but the dangerous permission needs a runtime permission from API level 23 **(Marshmallow)** and here's the lame **catch** for you since the pre Marshmallow devices doesn't had any concept like Runtime permission,  so the solution you want will only work in pre Marshmallow devices (and obviously that's not what you want)
- The permission dialog isn't handled by the application, the OS takes care of this.

Here's the [official link](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Understanding-App-Permissions) to the Android guide to App Permissions

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is possible. You can't hide the deny option in the app permission option.
the whole point of google giving these option was to try to protect user privacy.

The best option would be to convince the user why they should allow you the location permission.

And now Google has enforced a more strict policy for the app developer. And any unethical way can make your app banned or even worse your dev account ban.

Answer (score 1):

You can't control the permission request, but.

- You could have a view that prompt user to enable location permission which will prompt the location service to be switch on if it is not switched on and allow permission to your app to access location data.
- In your application class, you can create a listener that listens for the status of the location service, if its on or off. you can also check if permission is given on by the user to access location in the listener. so at any point, the status change. your listener acts accordingly